# Creating distro-specific documentation on wiki.ros.org

Tags: ros, rosdistro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I can't seem to find instructions on how to make distro-specific documentation on wiki.ros.org.  For example, I have a package called skeleton_markers that has buttons labeled Electric, Fuerte and Groovy at the top.  However, no matter which button is selected, when I edit the page the changes appear on all three versions.  What is the magic for making changes to just one distribution's wiki page and not the others?

Thanks
patrick

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/84791/creating-distro-specific-documentation-on-wiki.ros.org/) by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4046 on 2013-09-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You would use a special wiki tag:

```
{{{#!wiki version cturtle
`openni_camera` is not available in C Turtle. Select a newer distro above.
}}}
```

An example page to look at would be openni_camera: http://wiki.ros.org/openni_camera

A number of the turtlebot pages actually end up creating a new page and including it:

```
{{{#!wiki version electric fuerte
<<Include(turtlebot_bringup/Tutorials/pre_groovy/TurtleBot Bringup)>>
}}}

{{{#!wiki version groovy
<<Include(turtlebot_bringup/Tutorials/groovy/TurtleBot Bringup)>>
}}}
```

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2013-09-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2013-09-29**:
Thanks @fergs.  The only extra piece of info I needed was to use an extra pair of { and } when enclosing another block like {{{{#!wiki version groovy {{{$ rosmake $ roslaunch package launchfile.launch}}}}.